# How to get the list of external tables in oracle schema 11g

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I want to get the list of only external tables in oracle.
i tried to get the list using Select * from tab . But it return list of all the table including actual and external . But i only want list of external tables

Comment: Looks like a perfectly good question to me. Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
select *
from all_external_tables;
```

to see all external tables your user as access to. To see them for a specific schema/user:

```
select *
from all_external_tables
where owner = 'ARTHUR';
```

If you only want to see the ones *owned* by your current user, use

```
select *
from user_external_tables;
```

To see all table that are *not* external tables use this:

```
select ut.table_name
from user_tables ut
where not exists (select 42
                  from user_external_tables uet
                  where uet.table_Name = ut.table_name);
```

More details in the manual:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_1092.htm#REFRN20074
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_5490.htm#REFRN26286

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the list of only actual tables?

Comment: Mean List of tables owned by my user (Select * from tab) - (select * from all_external_tables) = (I want to get this list)